# In-app payment still says it's in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I built a in-app payment for one of my iPhone apps. It worked in sandbox mode.

I submitted my app to the app store and it got accepted. I even submit my in app payment. It got accepted and it's status is 'ready for sale'.

However, when I go get my app in the app store, it still says it's in sandbox?

Is there something in MKStoreKit that you have to transfer environments, or does it take some time for it to change?

I currently pulled it from the store because of it. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-released my app today so I could get it and see if the in app payment would work. Surprisingly, it worked and it wasn't in sandbox mode! So I guess it just takes time for apple's servers to make the change.

If anyone else had this problem, don't fret like I did! Just wait and be patient. Hold for developer release and wait around 24 hours and you should be good!

**Here's the real solution (edit):**

- Set your availability date to the future so it will be removed from the app store
- Set your availability date to the day it is so it will re appear

Comment: The bottom statement is not a real solution. I want to warn everyone that when you change your availability date as to remove the app from the appstore you end up resetting your apps rankings... If you are at the top of the top paid list or top free list in a category your app will fall back to the bottom and your knock-off competitor scum will rise ahead of you.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  Are you using your Test User ID or a real Apple ID?

Comment: Wait, you mean to not use a sandbox account? But use a real account? Then yes, I am logged in with a real Apple ID.

Comment: More as in, not logged in under sandbox mode. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

When this happens, it's usually because you previously used the same device for testing IAP in sandbox mode. To fix, just go into "Settings", then go to "Store", then log out and back in again. That should clear that up, assuming that you are actually using the archived app that you downloaded from iTunes, rather than your dev copy.